# Recycler View list modifying all the items when I delete one

Tags: java, android, json, list, android-recyclerview

I inserted a Recycler view on my app to make a shopbasket list.

Now I have two problems. When I copy my mUsers list to a JSON, all the items of the list copy the Values of the last item (e.g. If I have a list = [1,2,3,4] when I copy it to Json it transforms to [4,4,4,4]).

On my Recycler view, the items are showing correctly, but when I delete one item from the list, it transforms the list below it (e.g. If I have a list [1,2,3,4] and delete 2, the list transforms in [1,3,3].

Here is my RecyclerView Code:

```
public class LineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LineHolder> {

    private final List<Option> mUsers;

    public LineAdapter(ArrayList users) {
        mUsers = users;
    }

    @Override
    public LineHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new LineHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.main_line_view, parent, false));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(LineHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.title.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%s",
                mUsers.get(position).getNome().label
        ));
        holder.subtitle.setText(String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "Detalhes: %s",
                mUsers.get(position).getDados()
        ));
        lista.add(mUsers.get(position));

        holder.deleteButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                removerItem(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers != null ? mUsers.size() : 0;
    }

    public List<Option> getList(){
        return mUsers;
    }

    public void updateList(Option user) {
        insertItem(user);
    }

    private void insertItem(Option user) {
        mUsers.add(user);
        notifyItemInserted(getItemCount());
    }

    private void removerItem(int position) {
        mUsers.remove(position);
        notifyItemRemoved(position);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(position, mUsers.size());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the mistery, the code is working. The problem was when I was inserting to the list, I was using the same object everytime (I only updated it), so the pointer on every position was pointing to the same object.